# What is the best way to allow several methods on the controller without adding on routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi everybody I'm from the old school using rails 2.

Actually I'm using rails 4 and I'm trying to find a way to create methods on the controller without writting

On RAILS 2 used: **(only needed to write the name on the controller)**

```
#controller
def report_a
end

def report_b
end

def report_c
end

...and whatever def

#ROUTES
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

On RAILS 4

```
#controller
def report_a
end

def report_b
end

def report_c
end

#ROUTES
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

The problem is when I create a view report like this: (views/reports/report_a.html.erb)

```
<%= form_tag :action=>"report_a" do %>
<% end %>
```

I get this message:

```
No route matches [GET] "/reports/report_a"
```

To resolve this issue and doing Rails instruccions works like this:

```
#controller
def report_a
  @users= User.search(params[:name])
end

def result_report_a
  @users= User.search(params[:name])
end

#view/reports/report_a.html.erb
<%= form_tag :action=>"result_report_a" do %>
<% end %>

#routes.rb
get  "reports#report_a"
post "reports#result_report_a"
get  "reports#report_b"
post "reports#result_report_b"
get  "reports#report_c"
post "reports#result_report_c"
```

Also I found this better way:

```
#controller reports.rb
def search_report_a
  report_a
  render :report_a
end

def report_a
  @users = User.where(:name=>params[:name])
end

def search_report_b
  report_b
  render :report_b
end

def report_b
 @users = User.where(:address=>params[:address])
end
...

#Routes.rb
resources :users do
  match 'search_report_a', :via => [:post,:get], :on => :collection
  match 'search_report_b', :via => [:post,:get], :on => :collection
  ...
end
```

Is there any other way to create methods without adding all inside ROUTES.RB ?

Any suggestions or the only way is adding get and post?

Imagine a case where you have several methods.

Comment: a report doesn't have a show page? it makes the most sense to just use the id of the report if you're going to have lots of reports.

Comment: I used a def in the controller to make searches and export information.

Comment: For example def report_client end  , a view report report_client.html.erb and inside on def report_clien used format.html, format.pdf and format.xls

Answer (score 0):

Best approach in Rails is to use REST architecture. Your controller should be able to view, create, update and destroy some resource (of course all actions are not mandatory).

For example:

```
def ReportsController
  def index
    # Actions to show links to all possible reports
  end

  def show
    # Show report based on params
  end
end
```

Your `#show` method may show any of report (report_a, report_b, etc) just by checking param from GET request.

And you don't need to make all logics inside `#show` method. It would be better to place report-related logic in, maybe, some service objects.